# Adding admin account check

Tags: php, sql, admin, account

I have recently started learning PHP and have encountered some trouble. I looked at some other answers on here but still can't work it out so appologies.

I am trying to add a check to see if a user account is admin or not and then direct to an admin page if it is or to the index page if it is not an admin account. In my user table I have a column called "user_type" and the admins are set to "admin". How would I make my login code check for this and redirect appropriately?

```
    <?php

    ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db_tc"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tbl_users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// Password Hashing
$mypassword = hash("sha512", $mypassword);

//SQL injection protection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$ar=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($ar['user_type']=='admin')
{
 header('Location: admin.php');
}
else
{
 header('Location: index.html');
}

// Count table rows.
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

    $_SESSION["login"] = ("usernameEntered");
    header("location:index.html");
}

else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

UPDATED ANSWER:

Thank you for the help everyone. For users wanting to view to final working code here it is:

```
$ar=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Count table rows.
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

if($ar['user_type']=='admin')
{
 header('Location: adminhome.php');
}
else
{
 header('Location: index.html');
}

}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Comment: Mysql functions are deprecated.  You should use mysqli or PDO.  Prepared statements will protect against sql injection.

Comment: It will likely be more performant for you to add a LIMIT clause to your SQL query; I'm assuming there should only be a maximum of one row with username (and password). Were you not subsequently using the row data as @Lithilion answers, you would be able to make it even more efficient by using a COUNT. Also, I note you are using stripslashes before mysql_real_escape_string; if this is because you have magic_quotes_gpc enabled, you might want to consider disabling this. :)

Comment: Ah I have not looked into counts much. Would this be simple to do? Trying not to overload myself too early on in learning PHP.

Comment: @AlexW, Relatively straightforward; instead of using `SELECT *` with `mysql_num_rows`, you could use `SELECT COUNT(*)` with checking the count returned. A good tutorial is http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp. But because you need to check the `tbl_users.user_type` property, you can't use COUNT here. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($ar['user_type']=='admin')
{
 header('Location:http://example.com/admin.php');
}
else
{
 header('Location:http://example.com/index.php');
}
```

btw.: Please don't use sha512. Use blowfish instead!
Blowfish needs a salt. Sha512 doesn't so you can't get the passowrd through a hashtable with blowfish. The second thing is that blowfish needs more time to hash, so a bruteforce attack is not possible too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I shall look into blowfish. Thank you.

Comment: It still redirects to the same page. How can I handle it going to index.html if they are not admin? Sorry. I am still learning

Comment: Thank you. The issue I have now is no matter what is entered it always directs to the same page, even if the login info is wrong :s

Comment: Can you please update your script on the page so I can have a look? Maybe you implemented it wrong...

Comment: Oh my fault. I'm sorry. Please place the if-else clause right after your ob_end_flush();

Comment: Almost there thank you. The admin account directs to admin.php which is great but now wrong details still take you to index.html instead of "Wrong username or password".

Comment: @Lithilion: would you edit your answer to explain why Blowfish should be preferred to SHA512?